# ldapsearch: no result when objectClass in search filter

Tags: openldap

I have an open-ldap-server configuration with a translucent_proxy

This is to enrich the companies ldap server entries with local attributes.
In general it works fine.

I have a company ldap server: `ldap.c.com`, this one serves 
`dc=company,dc=com` and the usual subtrees (`ou=People,group`)

I have a local ldap server: `ldap.my.c.com`, this one serves an overlay of the `ou=People,dc=company,dc=com`.

so I could ask

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.c.com/ (uid=frank) mail mailLocalAddress
```

and will get something like

```
dn:uid=frank,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com
mail: f.name@company.com
```

and when asking my local ldap server the same question

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.my.c.com/ (uid=frank) mail mailLocalAddress
```

I will get my enriched result of

```
dn:uid=frank,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com
mail: f.name@company.com
mail: frank@my.c.com
mailLocalAddress: frank@my.c.com
mailLocalAddress: nick@my.c.com
```

FINE!

But when requesting any objectClass in the filter rule

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.my.c.com/ (&(uid=frank)(objectClass=posixAccount)) mail mailLocalAddress
```

gives me no results at all:

```
#search result
search: 2
result: 0 success
```

But the records do definitively have objectClasses of top,Person, inetorgPerson,posixAccount and some more set.
So what am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing an unauthenticated ldapsearch, this **could** be the problem. First try to verify if you can see the objectClasses this way with:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.my.c.com/ "(uid=frank)" objectClass
```

If this gives you no output you have probably some acl set, which prohibits you from seeing that. You can check them locally with something like (depending on your setup):

```
sudo ldapsearch -LLLQY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config "(olcDatabase=hdb)" olcAccess
```

There you can see who has access to that attributes and can use an authenticated ldapsearch (also depending a little bit on youre setup):

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.my.c.com/ -WD "uid=frank,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com" "(&(uid=frank)(objectClass=posixAccount))" mail mailLocalAddress
```